# jQuery preloading of external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say my main site is called

```
mainsite.com
```

On my mainsite.com I have a bunch of external links, such as:

```
external.com/search.php?type=xxx&date=xxx&id=xxx&product=xxx
```

When my visitors click on these links they load fine for all but one problem. They take 20-30 seconds to load!

The reason for this is the target URL on external.com is performing a product search.

So what I'm finding is my visitors are leaving before the link loads!

Anyone have any solutions I can try?

I can not make any changes to `external.com` as it's not my site! I can only add something to `mainsite.com`.

Comment: Use a different search provider? Not sure what other advice one *could* give.

Comment: I don't quite see the reason for all the downvotes. It's actually a valid question eventhough there's no real solution for it.

Comment: This is horrible and will not solve your speed issue (you obviously can't solve that as it's not *your* speed issue!), but make the links on your site open a page with a hidden iframe that loads the external site.  That way you can show some kind of "loading - please wait" message and/or graphic and then just fill the page with the iframe and show it when it's loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX to load the remote sites into a hidden DIV as soon as your main page loads. When the user clicks on the link, hide the main DIV and show the corresponding DIV.  Since AJAX runs asynchronously in the background, the loading will happen while the user is reading the main page, and hopefully it will be done by the time they click on the link.

Another option is to use AJAX at the time the user clicks on the link. While waiting for the page to arrive, display a spinner and a message saying "This takes a while, please wait...".

Comment: Nice idea to preload everything, in a perfect world, but that will heavily task the server at the external site, loading every linked page/query for every visitor to the main site.  Using ajax to get the page and saying "loading..." is a nicer way to do it, despite obviously not resolving the wait issue (and having possible issues with script and style includes).

Comment: JavaScript isn't magic, it can't make time run faster. If the server takes a long time to respond, you have to wait.

Comment: Thanks Barmar ... I should have explained that i have multiple links on the same page which all point to a different product!

Comment: I didn't think that JS *could* make time run faster, but thanks for clarifying :p

Comment: I accept there is nothing i can do with regards to the loading time ... but im trying to understand if i can do the following ... When the user clicks on the link i open another page on my site which displays a 'timer' icon and message. While this is displayed on the new page it also requests the real page from the external site and once this is returned it automatically hides the timerer message and loads in the external site? if this is possible can anyone show me a example? normally i only get involved in html/css and my developer tells me this is not possible? hence my question on SOF.

Comment: @Trevor It's a bad idea to do this with ajax as there will be issues with included and linked files in the head of the loaded document.  Look at using an iframe instead.